# Compile error when running cargo bench (criterion/serde)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, serde, rust-criterion

I added following lines to the `cargo.toml` of my project in order to benchmark my code:

```
[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.3"

[[bench]]
name = "samples"
harness = false
```

After running `cargo bench`, I get a lot of errors similar to the following:

```
Compiling criterion v0.3.4
error[E0603]: module `export` is private
   --> C:\Development\Rust\cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\criterion-0.3.4\src\connection.rs:201:17
    |
201 | #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ private module
    |
note: the module `export` is defined here
   --> C:\Development\Rust\cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\serde-1.0.123\src\lib.rs:275:5
    |
275 | use self::__private as export;
```

The error message looks to me that there is a problem between `serde` and `criterion`. But I did not find this error message in either project issues, so there may be a hidden reason in my workspace.

Some additional information:

- the project is compiled using the nightly toolchain
- there is just one explicit dependency (proc macros) in the `cargo.toml` which transitively references `syn`, `quote` and `proc-macro2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `serde` version and `serde_derive` version in your dependency graph are mismatched. You need to use `cargo update` to bring them in sync. The two must have the identical version number always.